# How search with strength in mgo Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, search, mgo

basically i have this query that searches from an array of names...now i want to make it case insensitive

in GO

```
err = c.Find(bson.M{
        "name": bson.M{
            "$in": names,
        },
    }).All(&res)
```

Result
search by **Raíz** name

1 document

search by **raíz** name
0 document

I would like the query to be something like this:

```
db.getCollection('g-se_tags').find({'name':'raíz', }).collation( { locale: "es", strength: 1 } )
```

Result
search by **Raíz** name

1 document

search by **raíz** name
1 document

Comment: Ditch `mgo` for good. It's been unmaintained for many years. Use the official mongo-go driver.